# Como usar las clases de una aplicación WebForms para una aplicación de consola C#

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo una aplicación en Webforms con la estructura correspondiente, donde mis clases estan en la carpeta "App_Code", requiero una aplicación de consola para automatizar ciertas cosas y esta requiere usar ciertas funciones de unas clases, hay manera de hacerlo?

Saludos

Comment: Pero la aplicacion de consola seria un proyecto distinto al web. El problema es que el proyecto como lo describes no compila a una dll que podrias referenciar, o puedes validar que se trata de un Web Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de poner las clases en App_Code crea un tercer proyecto 'Helper' dónde definas funciones que normalmente utilizes en otros proyectos.

Cua´dno las tengas ahí haz una referencia des de los otros proyectos a este 3r proyecto (des de bin --> botón derecha --> Add Reference).

Ya puedes utilizar funciones para ambos proyectos :) (Haz un using y el nombre del namespace para poder tener acceso a las funciones)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mover esas clases a un nuevo proyecto de Biblioteca de clases y añadir una referencia a dicho proyecto tanto en el de consola como el web.